# Can't display state values in React child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

In the parent component, I render a list of users. Each user is a User item child component. 
I map a state array of objects to render each **listitem** as user. It renders the correct amount of people, but the data is empty.

Below is the relevant code of my parent component.

```
const Search = ({
    auth: { isAuthenticated, user },
    getUsers,
    user: { users, loading }
}) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        getUsers();
        console.log(sunData);
    }, []);

    const [filteredUsersList, setFilteredUsersList] = useState({
        users: [],
        isFetching: false
    });

    //FILTER usersList.users ACCORDING TO VALUES IN sunData ARRAY
    useEffect(() => {
        // update the usersList
        const updatedUsersList = [];
        // //foreach index de usersList, si usersList.users[i]
        if (!usersAPIList) {
            return console.log("isEmpty");
        } else {
            for (let [key, userInfo] of Object.entries(users)) {
                //console.log(userInfo.username);
                if (sunData.indexOf(userInfo.sun) !== -1) {
                    updatedUsersList.push(userInfo);
                }
            }
        }

        setFilteredUsersList({ users: updatedUsersList, isFetching: false });
        console.log(updatedUsersList);
    }, [sunData]);

    return (
            <div className="usersList">
                <ul>
                    {filteredUsersList.users.map(userItem => (
                        <UserListItem user={userItem} />
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
    );
};

Search.propTypes = {
    getUsers: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    user: state.user
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUsers })(Search);
```

And here is the child component.

```
const UserListItem = ({
    auth: { isAuthenticated },
    user: { username, sun, bio, canBeMessaged },
    getUserById
}) => {
    return (
        <li>
            <div className="namephoto">
                <img src={DefaultIcon} alt="Default avatar" />
            </div>

            <div className="userListInfo">
                <h1>{username}</h1>

                {sun}
                <div className="userListBio">{bio}</div>
            </div>
            <div className="userListActions">
                {canBeMessaged ? <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i> : ""}
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
            </div>
        </li>
    );
};

UserListItem.propTypes = {
    auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    getUsersById: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    auth: state.auth,
    user: state.user
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUserById })(UserListItem);
```

The filteredUsersList.users logs correctly too. I don't see where the problem is and why the data won't display in the **listitem**.

Here is the output of filteredUsersList.users [image: filteredUsersList]

Comment: Did you try to log `username, sun, bio, canBeMessaged` inside your child component ?

Comment: @Hurobaki I did and it's undefined

Comment: Then your problem comes from your Parent component. Could you show me the output of `filteredUsersList`. And try to log `userItem` inside you `.map` method ?

Comment: Try naming your `user` prop something like `userDetails` in `UserListItem`. E.g. `<UserListItem userDetails={userItem} />` - I think redux is overwriting your user prop because you declare `mapStateToProps` at the end of your UserListItem component.

Comment: @Hurobaki I edited the question with a screenshot of the output

Comment: @AndyMardell I tried it, and it doesnt work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your redux overwrites your prop `user` inside your child component.

### First solution

Rename your `UserListItem` prop

```
<ul>
  {filteredUsersList.users.map(userItem => (
    <UserListItem userInfo={userItem} />
  ))}
</ul>

const UserListItem = ({
    auth: { isAuthenticated },
    userInfo: { username, sun, bio, canBeMessaged }, //from parent
    user, //from redux
    getUserById
})
```

### Second solution

Rename your redux prop inside your child component

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    authRdx: state.auth,
    userRdx: state.user
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUserById })(UserListItem);

const UserListItem = ({
    authRdx: { isAuthenticated },
    user: { username, sun, bio, canBeMessaged }, //from parent
    userRdx, //from redux
    getUserById
})
```

If the two solutions above didn't work, you should try to remove redux to debug step by step. Just keep your `.map()` and try to log prop from child component.

I hope it helps, feel free to add comments if you're still stuck

Comment: Glad to hear it, if my post helped you please consider to upvoting and accepting as answer, thanks !